# Queue from a family queue that supports presentation doesn't work [Vulkan]

Tags: c++, gpu, vulkan

I'm following [this tutorial on Vulkan](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Introduction) and I tried to see if it actually worked with different queues for drawing and presenting the image of the triangle. [My GPU supports presentation with every queue family](https://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/displayreport.php?id=2675#queuefamilies) but it actually works only when I use a queue from the first or second family, not the third. Is there anything wrong with the code or is something like that possible?

Comment: Please provide the code where you verify that the queue family you are using does in fact support presentation. Also, show the code where you perform a present operation on a queue from that family.

Comment: [This is the code](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/code/15_hello_triangle.cpp).

Comment: Clearly, that's not your code.

Comment: @j00hi TBH I can't see that he has asserted that was 'his' code but just that he was using that tutorial.

Comment: @SimonF Maybe my comment was a bit misleading --- it wasn't meant to be directed towards code ownership or copyright issues. What I actually wanted to point out: The tutorial code uses the same queue for drawing and presentation. We can not see the code changes w.r.t. "different queues for drawing and presenting the image". Therefore, we can not help if the code changes are not provided.